# Bootstrap 3 - adjust CSS based on size

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I know I can adjust layout depending on the screen size using `col-md` or `col-sm`, but can I use these same prefixes to adjust certain css properties. For example, I have section frames that have the property `padding:20px;`- this is great for `md` and `lg` screen sizes, but for smaller sizes I need to remove this padding. Is this built into bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You can set media query depending your parent class relation for ex.

```
<div class="container photoswide-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 no-padding">
                 Your Details
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<style>
@media(max-width:687px){
        .no-padding{
            padding-left: 0px;
            padding-right: 0px;
        }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you really trying to do. Maybe you could provide some of your code.

However the column-definitions you are talking about are built into bootstrap using media queries.

```
/* bootstrap css for small screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
    float: left;
  }
  .col-sm-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
  }
  /* and some more */
}
```

You can of course adjust these style rules and add or remove paddings. However it is recommended to not edit the original bootstrap file but to create a new one overwriting the bootstrap rules.

Your custom css file could contain rules like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .sections .col-sm-1, .sections .col-sm-2 /* and so on */ {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```